# Calculate Star rating based on webform submissions

Tags: rating

Is there a module to calculate Average Vote based on webform submissions?

Explanations:

I have a Webform which looks like this. So when a user submits the form i need a average value to be calculated which i can show as star rating some where on another page.

[image]

Does it need a custom module ?

Any clues ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should create a fivestar field in your webform and than create a custom module which calculate the rating and save it to a fivestar field.

Comment: follow the above approach

Comment: How about Poll ? Should i change the webform to a poll (if i could for multi questions). Wouldn't it be a easier path?

Comment: I don't think that you can add multiple questions in a poll. So webform will suits you.